# NHibernate does not work with tree object

Tags: c#, nhibernate, tree, fluent-nhibernate

i have this class that maps a tree of `Tag` objects :

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; set; }
    private IList<Tag> childTag = new List<Tag>();
    public virtual IEnumerable<Tag> ChildTag
    { get { return childTag.ToArray(); } }

    public virtual void Add(Tag child)
    { childTag .Add(child); }

    public virtual bool Remove(Tag child)
    { return childTag .Remove(child); }
}
```

with this map:

```
public TagMap()
    {
        Id(x => x.Id)
            .Column("Kint_T01_IdTag")
            .GeneratedBy.Assigned();
        HasMany(x => x.ChildTag)
                .KeyColumn("ParentId")
                .Cascade.All()
                .Access.CamelCaseField().ReadOnly();
    }
```

when i run this test

```
        Tag Tag= fixture.Build<Tag>().Do(x => x.Add(fixture.Create<Tag>())).Create();
        Tag TagActual;

        using (IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
        {
            uow.openConnection();
            uow.BeginTran();
            uow.TagRepository.Create(Tag);
            uow.commit();
            Tag.Rmove(Tag.ChildTag.First());
            uow.TagRepository.Update(Tag);
            uow.commit();
            uow.closeConnection();

            uow.openConnection();
            TagActual = uow.TagRepository.GetById(Tag.Id);
            TagActual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(Tag);
            uow.closeConnection();
        }
```

it fails because TagActual.ChildTag contains a child even if i remove it from parent collection.

debugging the test i see that after

```
uow.TagRepository.Create(Tag);
uow.commit();
```

two record are isnerted in table and `parent` property of children is set correctly

`Tag.Rmove(Tag.ChildTag.First());` work correctly and after that the collection is empty

but after

```
uow.TagRepository.Update(Tag);
uow.commit();
```

nothing change in table and 'parent' filed is still set.

In this way the test failed because TagActual has a collection of children while this should be empty

Why NHibernate correctly manage the `add` operation but not the `remove`

Is there a way to do it without adding `Parent` property to my object and manually manage it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find it :)

i done 2 mistakes:

- `.ReadOnly();` in map, it's useless
- forgot beginTrans in test case

test must be written so

```
Tag Tag= fixture.Build<Tag>().Do(x => x.Add(fixture.Create<Tag>())).Create();
    Tag TagActual;

    using (IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork())
    {
        uow.openConnection();
        uow.BeginTran();
        uow.TagRepository.Create(Tag);
        uow.commit();
        uow.BeginTran();
        Tag.Rmove(Tag.ChildTag.First());
        uow.TagRepository.Update(Tag);
        uow.commit();
        uow.closeConnection();

        uow.openConnection();
        TagActual = uow.TagRepository.GetById(Tag.Id);
        TagActual.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(Tag);
        uow.closeConnection();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how NHibernate is designed, according to http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#example-parentchild

Basically the solution is in adding an extra property "Parent" which is responsible for the relationship:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int Description { get; private set; }
    private IList<Tag> childTag = new List<Tag>();
    private Tag parentTag;
    public virtual IEnumerable<Tag> ChildTag { get { return childTag.ToArray(); } }

    public virtual void Add(Tag child) { childTag .Add(child); }
    public virtual bool Remove(Tag child) { return childTag .Remove(child); }
}
```

with this map:

```
public TagMap()
{
    Id(x => x.Id)
        .Column("Kint_T01_IdTag")
        .GeneratedBy.Assigned();
    Reference(x => x.ParentTag).Access.CamelCaseField();
    HasMany(x => x.ChildTag)
            .Inverse()
            .KeyColumn("ParentId")
            .Cascade.AllDeleteOrphan()
            .Access.CamelCaseField().ReadOnly();
}
```

Now everything should work as expected...

Comment: byt i dont want user give access to parent property outside of my class. only way to link parent and child must be the AddChild method

Comment: You can use the Access.CamelCaseField() on a reference as well. I just gave the basic direction.

Comment: I had tried it but with found no way to access private property in map, it simply does not compile

Comment: found now this link for mapping private fields: https://github.com/jagregory/fluent-nhibernate/wiki/Mapping-private-properties last one seem best to me if I have to use the parent property

Comment: why you use .Inverse on ManyToMany? for me is the parent tag responsible for having to save his child if it is added

Comment: First of all, this is a OneToMany. Secondly, You only change the childtag and not the parent when you add the child to the parent, at least this is how NHibernate sees it.

Comment: yes, sorry OneToMany. See my answer now. i somply do nothing on child, i only work with parent and want the child to be update in consequence